# postgresql custom cast to match different case types

Tags: entity-framework-6, postgresql-9.2, jsonb, devart

Some backgrounds, I am using:

- Entity framework 6.1
- Devart.Data.PostgreSql 7.11.1229
- Devart.Data 5.0.2021
- Postgresql 9.2

Because of some abstract OO modeling, EntityFramework is forced to perform some unions over different tables, some of which might contain a JSONB column, others not. Essentially this looks as follows:

```
select
    c1,
    c2,    
    case when 
        c4 = true then c3 
        else cast(null as varchar) 
    end as c3,
    c4
from (
    select
        id as c1,
        name as c2,
        attributes as c3,
        true as c4
    from
        myjsonbtable
    union all
    select
        id as c1,
        name as c2,
        null as c3,
        false as c4
    from
        mynormaltable
) as union_all
```

When you run this query, Postgresql will provide the following error;

```
ERROR:  CASE types character varying and jsonb cannot be matched
```

this results from the following line of code:

```
case when c4 = true then c3 else cast(null as varchar) end as c3
```

which we could fix like this:

```
case when c4 = true then c3 else cast(null as jsonb) end as c3
```

Provided we hit EF with a stick. More easy would be if we could tell Postgresql how to cast these types:

something like:

```
create cast (varchar as jsonb) with function to_jsonb(anyelement) as implicit;
```

But I am wondering, would a CASE actually be able to perform an implicit CAST from character varying to jsonb to match types?

Or perhaps anybody as another a brillaint idea to either, either from a Postgresql or EntityFramework standpoint.

**Edit: see the submitted code example**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DevartExample
{

    [Table("BaseClass")]
    public class BaseClass
    {
        [Index]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("ClassWithJsonb")]
    public class ClassWithJsonB : BaseClass
    {
        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public string Json { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("ClassWithoutJsonb")]
    public class ClassWithoutJsonB : BaseClass
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class DevartDbProvider : DbContext
    {
        public IDbSet<BaseClass> BaseClass
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public IDbSet<ClassWithJsonB> ClassWithJsonB
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public IDbSet<ClassWithoutJsonB> ClassWithoutJsonB
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public DevartDbProvider() : base("DevartExample")
        {
            Database.Log = s => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s); };
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DevartDbProvider devartDbProvider = new DevartDbProvider();

            devartDbProvider.BaseClass.FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }
}
```

Outputs this query:

```
SELECT 
"Limit1"."C1",
"Limit1"."Id",
"Limit1"."C2",
"Limit1"."C3"
FROM ( SELECT 
    "Extent1"."Id",
    CASE WHEN ( NOT (("Project2"."C1" = true) AND ("Project2"."C1" IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (("Project1"."C1" = true) AND ("Project1"."C1" IS NOT NULL))) THEN '0X' WHEN ("Project2"."C1" = true) AND ("Project2"."C1" IS NOT NULL) THEN '0X0X' ELSE '0X1X' END AS "C1",
    CASE WHEN ( NOT (("Project2"."C1" = true) AND ("Project2"."C1" IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (("Project1"."C1" = true) AND ("Project1"."C1" IS NOT NULL))) THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar) WHEN ("Project2"."C1" = true) AND ("Project2"."C1" IS NOT NULL) THEN "Project2"."Json" END AS "C2",
    CASE WHEN ( NOT (("Project2"."C1" = true) AND ("Project2"."C1" IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (("Project1"."C1" = true) AND ("Project1"."C1" IS NOT NULL))) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ("Project2"."C1" = true) AND ("Project2"."C1" IS NOT NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE "Project1"."MyProperty" END AS "C3"
    FROM   "BaseClass" AS "Extent1"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
        "Extent2"."Id",
        "Extent2"."MyProperty",
        true AS "C1"
        FROM "ClassWithoutJsonb" AS "Extent2" ) AS "Project1" ON "Extent1"."Id" = "Project1"."Id"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
        "Extent3"."Id",
        "Extent3"."Json",
        true AS "C1"
        FROM "ClassWithJsonb" AS "Extent3" ) AS "Project2" ON "Extent1"."Id" = "Project2"."Id"
    LIMIT 1 
)  AS "Limit1"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you cast `c3` to  `varchar`, something like: `case when c4 then c3::varchar else null::varchar end as c3`

Comment: The problem is that i don't control the query. it might be the result of the following line of code in Entity Framework:  context.Set<MyTable>().Where(t => t.Id == record_id).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: or more correctly dbContext.Set<AbstractClass>().Where(t => t.Id == record_id).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 0):

You are using fluent mappping (not XML mapping), aren't you? Make sure that the column type for the corresponding properties is set to jsonb: .HasColumnType("jsonb");

If this doesn't help, [send us](https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html) a small test project for reproducing the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. We are using the following data annotations to specify the datatype:  [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]. See example here: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/EF-JSON-Support.html. I think fluent api and data annotations accomplish the same? If so I will provide an example

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the same. Please provide a small test project for reproducing the issue.